# Storing images for my site in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm setting up a new website where users can upload images and make them available for other users to see.

Is it possible to setup an S3 bucket and use that to store all of the images (there could be tens to hundreds of thousands) and display them dynamically on the website or isn't S3 supposed to be used for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats a good fit for S3.

Although you are limited to 100 buckets, there are no limits to the number of files you can store in a bucket. Your files can be public or private with access via time expiring urls you can generate.

You can also easily link Amazons Cloudfront cdn to a bucket to get the benefits of distributed distribution.

Comment: Would it be ok to put all of the images uploaded by my users in one file inside one bucket or is there a better way?

Comment: @edwinNosh - Each image would be stored separately. Do you mean in one folder? S3 doesn't actually have the concept of folders although you can fake it by naming your files in such a special way. eg a file named `user1/image1.jpg` would appear to be in the `user1` folder. All the major S3 GUI tools support this convention and you can search a bucket using a prefix like `user1` to filter the results.

Comment: you can create folders in the bucket in the web management console.

Comment: If my bucket has hundreds of thousands of pictures. Is it efficient to have to search for the image by its name or ID every time you want to display it?

note: i'm setting up a flickr like service

Comment: @edwinNosh - yes, the console can "create folders" but they're fake folders as I described. This is something you'll need to be aware op when you start uploading files programmatically buts it works well and is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @edwinNosh - you dont have to search for the image everytime. Using the prefix for searching is only relevant if you want to list the contents of a folder and you don't know in advance what files it contains. I imagine in your case you would have all the image names in your database in which case you can just link to it with a url that looks something like: `http://bucketname/s3.amazonaws.com/myimagename.jpg`. or your can generate the private, expiring url and link using that instead.